# How to get the start time and duration of the SQL-queries to the specified tables in the database (Oracle 10g)?

Tags: oracle, oracle10g, awr

How to get the start time and duration of the SQL-queries to the specified tables in the database (Oracle 10g)?
I need information even about very short queries, which can be many, and which AWR not shows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why do you need such diagnostic? It's possible to turn on tracing for each user/session but I wouldn't recommend that since the DB will spend more resources on tracing than on the actual work.